# Another Woodcutting Dilemma

Tags: algorithm

After seeing a recent [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) question, I recall an interesting problem I once saw and solved, but have now forgotten the solution for. Hoping someone can point me in the correct direction.

You have `K` pieces of wood in a pile, with varying sizes. You are given `C` 'cuts' where you can cut a single piece of wood at any point in the wood, returning both the cut pieces back into the pile of wood. Your goal is to determine `M`, the smallest value for `max(pile) - min(pile)`.

Input:

```
Line 1: Two space separated characters, K C
Lines 2..K+1: A single real number representing the length of a piece of wood (of the K).
```

Output:

```
M
```

Constraints:

```
K < 500 000
C < 1 000
```

Limits

```
~10 sec runtime on an average PC with ~256 meg RAM limit'd.
```

Comment: I'm a skeptic: this sounds too much as a "please do my homework". Why not try yourself (again?) and post a specific programming related question when you get stuck?

Comment: I assure you I've done the problem, it was a greedy solution. Just struggling to recall the details and was hoping it was a somewhat (glaringly) obvious thing I'd missed.

Comment: Input format suggests SPOJ, the hardware spec could fit too.

Comment: It might well have been originally, the place I saw it was a Theory of Algorithms question from 2009 @ UCT.

Comment: You should define `max(pile)` and `min(pile)`. Length of longest and shortest boards, respectively, seems likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For i in {1, …, k}, let L<sub>i</sub> be the initial length of piece i and initialize C<sub>i</sub>, the number of equally spaced cuts of i, to 0. Repeat C times: let j = argmax<sub>i</sub> L<sub>i</sub>/(1 + C<sub>i</sub>) and increment C<sub>j</sub>.

Comment: You should be a bit more verbose if you want your answers to be understood. In the other woodcutting problem, I've only understood that what you meant was the complete answer a long time after.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks, as soon as I read this I got what you meant. You give all pieces of wood a 'cuts' count that starts at 0. You greedily choose the largest piece each time, based on it's initial length divided by 1 + it's 'cuts' count, and increment it's 'cuts' count by 1.

With a heap-based priority queue I think it can be solved in O(K + ClogK), definitely within time.

Thanks!

Comment: Must all C cuts be used?  If not, then you may need to stop early: consider a pile consisting of 2 equal-length boards, and C odd.